# QGIS mixing up CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I´ve just started working with QuantumGIS for my thesis. I ordered shapefiles with the CRS: ETRS 89 UTM Zone 33N, but QGis layer properties now shows the layer has a different CRS (namely SWERE99 TM) and i did not change anything. I´m puzzled and can´t figure out what´s the problem.
Thanks.
Katja

Answer (score 3):

SWERE99 and ETRS89 have the same projection definition, so it makes no difference. You can change the CRS by rightclick on the layer in the legend `-> Set CRS for layer`

Comment: Fine, that worked out. But now problem is: I can´t clip it with another shape-file (in CRS: PD/83 / Gauss-Kruger zone 4). They are overlayed but everytime I clip there´s no result. (When both are in the same CRS they don´t match).

Comment: For clipping, they must be saved in the same CRS. So you have to rightclick again `-> Save As...`, choose a different file name, but the same CRS as the other file originally has.